# Selenium ie driver cannot switch to window popup

Tags: selenium

Trying to use the `ieDriver.switchTo().window(windowHandle)` method to switch to a popup window but my test script stops and does not proceed.

When I close the window manually i get the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser
```

I know the window exists because I used the `ieDriver.getWindowHandles()` method to retrieve it.

All my protected mode settings are the same, I even tried to use the `'INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS'` technique to no avail.  Any other suggestions?

I'm running selenium 2.32.0 with IE9 on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: How is the popup created?

Comment: Can you show the code where `windowHandle` is created

Comment: Have you tried another way of solving this? Maybe pressing ALT+TAB will get you the desired result. I could have helped you in Ruby but I dunno anything about Java. Just proposing a different kind of solution..

Comment: I had the same experience, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python?answertab=active#tab-top) is the solution. It's written in python, hope you can convert codes.

Answer (score 1):

Above code isfor handling window pops. 
If you want to handle javascript popups like alerts, or confrmation popup, you need to use

> driver.SwitchTo.alert().accept();

or

> driver.SwitchTo.alert().dismiss();

hope it'll help you

Answer (score 0):

maybe the popup is generated, with iframe, then you have to use switchTo.frame();

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
  WebDriverWait webDriverWait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
  webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
  driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

First you will initialize a WebDriverWait object that will allow you to wait until some condition is met, in this case - alert is present.
Then, the driver will be switched to this alert,